# Render additional html at the beginning or end of action view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have Zend Framework MVC application with module structure like that above:

```
/application
  /layouts
    /sripts
      /layout.phtml
  /modules
    /default
      /controllers
        /IndexController.php
        /OtherController.php
      /views
        /scripts
          /index
            /index.phtml
            /second.phtml
            /third.phtml
            /fourth.phtml
          /other
            /index.phtml
            /second.phtml
            /third.phtml
            /fourth.phtml
```

In my layout.phtml i have a line

```
<div id="main">
    <?= $this->layout()->content ?>
</div>
```

I want to wrap rendered action views in every action of IndexController and OtherController, except fourth, with some code, like `<div id='top'></div>` at the beggining, and `<div id='bottom'></div>` at the end of rendered action view.
I don't want to do it manually in every action view *.phtml file. There are too many in real application, besides code looks messy with that solution.

How to do it?

Comment: you could probably do this with one or more [action helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html). Sounds like you have lots of code in your layout the could be pushed into [placeholders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder) or [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a layout file, you can echo a layout variable. This is usually where we put the html rendered by an action. You can append the rendering from several actions into a single layout variable, and they will be displayed in LIFO order. Here is how that variable is inserted into the layout file:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->myLayoutVariable; ?>
```

You can also set up a placeholder variable inside your layout file:

```
<?php echo $this->placeholder('myPlaceholderVariable'); ?>
```

In one of your view files, you can then provide the html content for this placeholder variable:

```
<?php
    $this->placeholder('myPlaceholderVariable')->append('<p>HTML GOES HERE</p>');
?>
```

If you don't set any value for the placeholder variable, nothing will be rendered in the layout file. But if you do set a value for that placeholder variable, it will be inserted into the html.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a different layout only for `IndexController` and `OtherController` : in the `init()` method of each controller, you can add the following:

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('some other layout');
```

Comment: I have too much application logic in layout.phtml (I know I shouldn't). Having two layout files doing 99% the same work would be problematic. I just need some prepend(), append(), and wrap() methods in my controllers init(), but don't know any...

Comment: The same way that you should not have application logic in `layout.phtml` (just like you mentioned), controllers should not have access to stuff like `prepend()`, `append()` and `wrap()` because these things are more specific to views.

One other solution I can see if you don't want to duplicate your `layout.phtml`, would be to set `$this->view` in `IndexController` and `OtherController` to something that extends `Zend_View`, and in there wrap your output by overriding `render()`...

Comment: Logic is maybe too big word, but there is some cookie handling and social stuff which for now I don't want to move or duplicate - layout is still changing. I temporary solved the problem by checking module, controller and action name in my My_Controller class and assingin `wrapper` decision variable to `view`. In layout.phtml conditional statements decide if wrap content or not. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#main").before(//insert header html here);
   $("#main").after(//insert footer html here);

});
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the fourth, but if you want to target a specific controller/action you could grab the window.location.href and make your function dependent on a specific URL you want to look for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need to do that in PHP, when application content is being rendered.